# Update rows with data from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the right way to write an sql that'll update all `type = 1` with the sum of totals of rows where parent = id of row with `type=1`.

Put simply:
update likesd set totals = sum of all totals where parent = id of row where type = 1

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "totals"
"3"     "1"     "1"         "US"        "6"
"4"     "2"     "3"         "US"        "6"
"5"     "3"     "3"         "US"        "5"
```

**Desired results**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "totals"
"3"     "1"     "1"         "US"        "17" ->6+6+5=17
"4"     "2"     "3"         "US"        "6"
"5"     "3"     "3"         "US"        "5"
```

**I was trying with (and failed)**

```
UPDATE  likesd a
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  parent, sum(totals) totalsNew
        FROM likesd
        WHERE b.parent = a.id 
        GROUP BY parent
        ) b ON a.id = b.parent
        SET a.totals = b.totalsNew;
```

Comment: What results did you get in your "Failure"

Comment: I would say, leave it as it is, and based on the child/parent relationship, show the total. That way you don't have a "calculated" field in some places and the math to get that calculated field in the rest. E.G. Leave it in the presentation layer.

Comment: @Elias. I get ` Unknown column 'b.parent' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Does ID 3 always get the total or if say id 5 is the parent should that get the total of just id's that have a parent of 5?

Comment: `Type = 1` will get the total. So if there are many `type=1` then all need to get updated with the sums() of their respective children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the multiple table syntax described [in the MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
update likesd a, (select parent, sum(totals) as tsum
       from likesd group by parent) b
set    a.totals = a.totals + b.tsum
where  a.type = 1 and b.parent = a.id;
```

The query updates one row and results in:

```
+------+------+--------+---------+--------+
| id   | type | parent | country | totals |
+------+------+--------+---------+--------+
|    3 |    1 |      1 | US      |     17 |
|    4 |    2 |      3 | US      |      6 |
|    5 |    3 |      3 | US      |      5 |
+------+------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

here is command that does what you want

```
update likesd as upTbl
        inner join
    (select 
        tbl.id, tbl.totals + sum(tbl2.totals) as totals
    from
        likesd tbl
    inner join likesd tbl2 ON tbl2.parent = tbl.id
    where
        tbl.type = 1
    group by tbl.id) as results ON upTbl.id = results.id 
set 
    upTbl.totals = results.totals;
```

tested on MySql 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

```
with update_cte(parent,totals)
as(select parent, sum(totals)totalsNew
FROM likesd where type=1 group by parent)
update a
set a.totals=b.totals
from likesd a join update_cte b on a.id=b.parent
```

Comment: MySQL does not support CTE's yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
update likesd
set totals = (
        select a.childTotals
        from (
            select sum(totals) as childTotals
            from likesd
        ) as a
    )
where id = parent and type = 1;
```

**Edit:** As per [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), using an implicit temp table to allow an update to the same table used in a nested SELECT statement.

Comment: This gives: `You can't specify target table 'likesd' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: How about that? Sorry, I've only got MS-SQL running on my machine so I'm guessing/reading on MySQL semantics.